# ggts, new groovy compiler version not available to project after installing for workspace

Tags: grails, groovy, ggts

Using GGTS 3.6.4

Just installed Groovy 2.4.1, and it shows up under Window=>Preferences; Groovy=>Compiler, and I see: "You are currently using Groovy Compiler version 2.4.1."

However, when I go to Project=>Properties; Groovy Compiler, I see only these 4 options under "Groovy compile level for project XxxxYyyyyZzzz":

- I don't care
- 2.1
- 2.3
- unspecified

I want to be able to designate 2.4 as the Groovy Compiler version for the project, but it's not there to pick!  I've stopped/started GGTS, to no avail. What can I do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try changing the file .settings/org.eclipse.jdt.groovy.core.prefs wherever your workspace is for that project.

set it to:

```
groovy.compiler.level=24
```

stop/start and see if that works.

Comment: Great! That worked, it compiles now, without the error about groovy compiler mismatch. But, under  Project=>Properties; Groovy Compiler, I see only these 4 options under "Groovy compile level for project XxxxYyyyyZzzz": it still shows the same 4 options, but now, none (blank) is selected.  I'll just leave it. Must be a GGTS defect.